# How to get field length in IE without counting placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

How can I tell the different with JS between field length of placeholder vs field content length in IE. I am trying to get the length of the content of an input field/text area but IE counts placeholder text as content.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="some_field" placeholder="Test" />

jQuery("#some_field").val().length //in Safari/Chrome/FF = 0 in IE7/8 = 4.
```

Comment: Placeholders don't work in IE<9.  If you're using a plugin to emulate it, then it's replacing the value with the placeholder, thus making a length of 4.

Comment: Hi Rocket, they are working natively with IE8 for me with an HTML5 form.

Comment: @brupm Then you have a very special IE8, as mine does not work natively.

Comment: Does your IE support `placeholder`? If not (and I guess so), are you using any dirty emulation frameworks that set the value to the placeholder? Then look up the docs of that framework.

Comment: Did you test it with *actual* IE8, or IE9 in IE8 mode?  Placeholders only work natively with IE >= 9.

Comment: Yeah upon further investigation the project is using query.f5.js - Duh.

Comment: @brupm: What's `query.f5.js`?

Comment: I do not have IE9 installed, but I wonder if the question would be relevant to IE9. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Rocket: https://github.com/akaspin/jquery.f5

Comment: @brupm: Turns out placeholders won't work in IE until IE 10!  So this won't work in IE9 either.

Comment: @brupm: In the [docs for jquery.f5](https://github.com/akaspin/jquery.f5/blob/master/readme.md), it tells you exactly how to solve this issue.  `.control.value()`.  According to the docs, use `$('#some-field').get(0).control.value()`

Answer (score 2):

While the `placeholder` attribute may not work in >IE9, it doesn't explain why the browser is arbitrarily interpreting the length of the `placeholder` attribute as the length of its value.

To make things more interesting, I was unable to replicate this behavior in IE7 or IE8. In both browsers I got a length of 0 when the field was empty.

Here's the script I ran: http://jsfiddle.net/ASmJX/1/

I also played with the `prop()` method to see if it made a difference. I suggest you do the same.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="some_field" placeholder="Test" />

<p>
    <button type="button" id="test_val">Check Length - val()</button>
    <button type="button" id="test_prop">Check Length - prop()</button>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('#test_val').on('click', function() {
    alert($("#some_field").val().length);
});

$('#test_prop').on('click', function() {
    alert($("#some_field").prop('value').length);
});
```

Perhaps there is more to your issue than an incompatible attribute.

Comment: Thank you, the issue here is I am using https://github.com/akaspin/jquery.f5 to mimic placeholders. So apparently there is no way to get around it, since the plugin sets the value to be the placeholder.

Comment: The OP was using a plugin to emulate placeholders in IE.  Actually, placeholders don't work in IE9, they'll be in IE10.  Anyway, the plugin emulates placeholders by coping the placeholder value to the input's value.  Thus, when checking the length, it's 4 (the length of the placeholder).

Comment: Ah... I hadn't seen the comment about the plugin until I refreshed the page. Seems like @Rocket found the answer in his last comment.